# Voltage limitations on AREF for Arduino

Tags: arduino, adc

The default for the Arduino A/D capability is a 5v reference.  Given the 10-bit A/D converter, this is 4.88mV per number from 0 to 1023.  The Arduino also supports setting the analog reference voltage to 1.1V, giving an accuracy approximately 5 times higher.

I wanted to try increasing that further.
The Arduino has an internal 32k ohm resistor on AREF, so I connected a 1M ohm resistor to Vcc.  The voltage reads 0.16V, but then A/D converter doesn't work.  Presumably there is a lower limit.  With 100k, it works, but the reference voltage is more than 1.1V, so there isn't much point.

Is it possible to set the reference voltage to less?

Comment: It's much better to get an instrumentation amplifier and use it to increase the voltage to the 5V range, if you're trying to detect a very small voltage.

Comment: Accuracy is a strange word to chose for the effect of decreasing the AREF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which Arduino you have but on page 377 the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2549.pdf) for the atmega2560 says Vref min for the adc is 1.0V.  So unfortunately that probably won't help you.

Answer (score 0):

analogReference(type)
EXTERNAL

Aref can be 0 to 5V but needs to be low impedance source and noise free.

Can you ensure the noise on Aref, signal and analog ground is < 1mV ?

The Uno is already obsolete and the Due has a 12bit ADC.  The more resolution you have, the greater attention is required to EMI, conducted and radiated noise on signals, ground and Aref.

Consider boosting the signal.

Comment: The Uno is obsolete?